# Why does my calculator automatically answer "0" before i can put my sign in?

Tags: java, eclipse

Somewhere around line 15 it gives me issues.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Main 
 {
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
 Scanner  sc = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner object created

 System.out.println("Enter your first number");
  int nr1 = sc.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter your second number");
 int nr2 = sc.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter your sign (+ , - , /, *)");
 String anvin = sc.nextLine();
 int ans = 0;
```

//somewhere around this line is where it is having the problems. it gives me the answer before i     can put in my sign;

```
 if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
 ans = nr1 + nr2;
 }
 else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
 ans = nr1 - nr2;
 }
 else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
 ans = nr1 * nr2;
 }
 else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
 ans = nr1 / nr2;
 }

System.out.println(ans);

System.out.println("To continue type yes");
String yes= sc.nextLine();

if(yes.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
return;

}
}
}
```

it answers "0" whatever I enter before I can put in my sign

```
Enter your first number
9
Enter your second number
9
Enter your sign (+ , - , /, *)
0
To continue type yes
```

please tell me what I did wrong and possibly correct it so I can understand further

Comment: Please indent your code so it's easier to understand for us. Aside from that, good question! Capitalization and punctuation could use work, but very readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `sc.nextInt()` lines to `Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())`. This should make your code work correctly.

EDIT: updated the code to include a while loop to make it so you can do multiple runs per your comment. This would also require you changing your last if statement to `break;` instead of `return;`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in ); //scanner object created

while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter your first number");
    int nr1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter your second number");
    int nr2 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter your sign (+ , - , /, *)");
    String anvin = sc.nextLine();
    int ans = 0;
    //somewhere around this line is where it is having the problems. it gives me the answer before i can put in my sign;
    if (anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
        ans = nr1 + nr2;
    } else if (anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
        ans = nr1 - nr2;
    } else if (anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
        ans = nr1 * nr2;
    } else if (anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
        ans = nr1 / nr2;
    }

    System.out.println(ans);
    System.out.println("To continue type yes");
    String yes = sc.nextLine();

    if (!yes.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: that got it working. Now I have to figure out why when I type "yes" to return it doesn't return

Comment: You don't even need that last part... No matter if you type "no", "bob", "joe", "random", or "yes", the end of the method will be hit. Which is the same as your return.

Comment: Is there a way I can make it so I can ask it to do another equation?

Comment: Yup yup, if on of the answers here was helpful it would be appreciated if you accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
String anvin = sc.nextLine();
```

to

```
String anvin = sc.next();
```

Also keep in mind that you might divide through zero ;-)

**Edit:**

also change

```
String yes= sc.nextLine();
```

to

```
String yes= sc.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you this, you can not only learn using objects but learn a better way of writing managed codes too,
`Calculator.java` -> a class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Instantiate
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Calculations calc = new Calculations();

    // Variable declarations
    double answer = 0, entry1 , entry2 ;
    char operator;

    // Start 
    System.out.println("***** Welcome to the Command line calculator program *****");
    System.out.print("Please enter the first number :");
    entry1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please enter the second number:");
    entry2 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please enter the operation : ");
    System.out.println("***** Operations :- + -> Add ; - ->Substract ; / -> Divide ; * -> Multiply ; ^ : Power *****");
    operator = input.next().charAt(0);

    // Switch case

    switch (operator){

        case '+' : answer = calc.add(entry1, entry2);
            break;
        case '-' : answer = calc.substract(entry1, entry2);
            break;
        case '/' : answer = calc.divide(entry1, entry2);
            break;
        case '*' : answer = calc.multiply(entry1, entry2);
            break; 
        case '^' : answer = calc.power(entry1, entry2); 
            break;
    }

    System.out.println(entry1 + " " + operator + " " + entry2 + " = " + answer);    
}
}`
```

`Calculations.java` -->another class holding calculations

```
import java.math.*;
public class Calculations {
    // Addition Method
    double add (double first, double second){
        double answer = first + second;
        return answer;
    }
    // Substraction Method
    double substract (double first, double second){
        double answer = first - second;
        return answer;
    }
    // Multiplication Method
    double multiply (double first, double second){
        double answer = first * second;
        return answer;
    }
    // Division Method
    double divide (double first, double second){
        double answer = first / second;
        return answer;
    }
    // Power Method
    double power(double a, double b){
        double answer =Math.pow(a, b);
        return answer;
    }

}
```

Comment: alright i will test that out and see if it has resolved my problems

Comment: And of course, if you wish to continue your current way then try changing `String anvin = sc.nextLine();` to `String anvin = sc.next();`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sc.nextLine();` use `sc.next();`